# Time limit for moving funds when employer changing 401k from one provider to another?

Tags: united-states, 401k

My employer is changing our 401k from Fidelity to Vanguard. In my employer's notification it stated all the things that it should have except it said "your current funds will be moved from FIS to Vanguard sometime later in 2017."

Is there a time limit on how long they will have to move my current funds or can they just do it whenever they feel like it?

Answer (score 3):

They gave advanced notice, so when the date is solidified, no one can say they didn't know anything. 
It's not as if the money is in limbo until then, it's still at fidelity. I am certain there will come time in '17 when you get a 30-60 day notice that the move will happen.

There are rules that employers must deposit the money within X days of withholding from your check. But I don't believe there's anything against warning you *too far* in advance that a change in provider is planned.